# how to overwrite default system key mapping in vim

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to map f1 to create a new tab so I add the following line

```
   map <F1> :tabnew <CR>
```

into my .vimrc and save it . But when I hit f1 in vim the GNOME TERMINAL MANNUAL window pops up rather than a new tab being created . So what should I do in this situation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Edit | Keyboard Shortcuts...` and remap or remove the shortcut.

Comment: @Ignacio : In which file the keyboard shortcuts are ?  thanks .

Comment: They're buried deep in gconf.